# Disable auto login upon registration in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication, registration

[**update1**] I am using the ClassiCraft theme and I have no idea where to customize the login and register forms

[**update2**] I know that the registration process does not go through wp_authenticate because I redefined it inside a plugin of mine

I am quite new in the Wordpress world (actually just got my hands on it for the first time yesterday) and I am having some difficulties finishing up a little project I am working on.

The project is rather simple (or so I thought) and consists in adding a confirmation link to email received upon registration in order to validate the email address provided to prevent using fake emails that the registrar does not even own.

I am about all done except that once I hit the register button it leads to log in the freshly created user.

I googled stuff like "wp disable auto login on registration" and whatnot but I have not been able to find anything that worked. I even tested a few plugins supposed to be doing exactly what I need but none of them worked.

Also, **I am not using any plugins for the registration/login forms** and it appears that the code in the wp-login.php file is actually not even used...

Would anyone have an idea? Thanks

Comment: I think you'll need a plugin for this. Because, when user use the registration form of wordpress, it's automatically create a user so it is logged him in. My first research of your questions leads me here : https://wordpress.org/plugins/pie-register/. Have you trie ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just tried but I did not really like the way the fields look on the page

Comment: Can you send me a picture of what it's look like and what it's wrong with ? Maybe i can help

Comment: Sure! Without pie-register [link](https://immobilier97.com/tmp/ss1.png), with pie-register [link](https://immobilier97.com/tmp/ss2.png)

Comment: I actually do not even know where to modify these login and registration fields that come with the theme. For sure, it's not coming from wp-login.php

Comment: Also I did not really find any option in pie-register to disable the auto login upon registration

Comment: What plugin are you using for the front registration, and the account where a user can add Real Estate adverts

Comment: I do not use any plugin for front registration, it is part of the theme

Comment: Ouch. I tried to code a plugin to achieve want you want, but without the theme configuration it's complicated. I'm gonna answer you with all the step i would to to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so without an access to the theme, i can't really answer you.

But i can tell you what I would try.

**1. Add action on `user_register` hook, to add a post meta that will be useful to check if user has confirm his email.**

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_has_confirm_email_user_meta');
function add_has_confirm_email_user_meta( $user_id ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'has_confirm_email', 0 );
}
```

**2. Prevent the user from log in automatically after registration.**

Here i can't tell you the hook that will works for you. For example, the hook for the wordpress registration is `user_register`, but if you have woocommerce, the hook I will use, would be `woocommerce_registration_redirect`. So try to find what hook is available after the registration with your theme.

In all case, the code in the function would be something like :

```
function custom_registration_redirect() {
    // Log out the user
    wp_logout();

    // The login url could be an other, with woocommerce for example it is : get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id')
    $login_url = wp_login_url();

    // Redirect on it
    wp_redirect( $login_url);
    exit;
}
```

It will also be necessary, to add a message on this page to alert the user, that he will receive an email to confirm his account.

**3. Prevent user from login when he submit the log in form**

Add action on wp_login hook to achieve that.

```
add_action('wp_login', 'prevent_user_from_login', 10, 2);
function prevent_user_from_login($user_login, $user = null ) {

    if ( !$user ) {
        $user = get_user_by('login', $user_login);
    }

    if ( !$user ) {
        // not logged in 
        return;
    }

    // Get user meta
    $has_confirm_email = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'has_confirm_email', true );


    if ( $has_confirm_email == '0' ) {
        // Clear cookies, a.k.a log user out
        wp_clear_auth_cookie();

        $login_url = wp_login_url();

        $login_url = add_query_arg( 'has_confirm_email', '0', $login_url);

        wp_redirect( $login_url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

**4. Add message on log in page if we get the `has_confirm_email` to 0**

```
add_filter('login_message', 'has_not_confirm_email_login_message');
function has_not_confirm_email_login_message($message) {

    if ( isset( $_GET['has_confirm_email'] ) && $_GET['has_confirm_email'] == 0 ) {
            $message =  '<div id="login_error">You have not confirmed your email.</div>';
    }

    return $message;
}
```

**5. Send the email with a link to confirm his email.**

You will need to generate a token to add to the url.
For the hook to change the default email sent by Wordpress, you can use `wp_new_user_notification_email` that is available since the 4.9 of Wordpress.

In the function itself you could do something like :

```
function wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname) {

    // Generate the token (there is other function available with php 7, but this one works great)
    $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));

    // Add the token to the user
    update_user_meta( $user->id, 'confirm_email_token', $token );

    // Get your login url
    $log_in_url = wp_login_url();

    // Add user id and token to the url       
    $url = add_query_arg(
        array(
            'token' => $token,
            'user_id' => $user->id
        ),
        $log_in_url
    );

    // 
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['subject'] = 'Welcome on our website, please confirm your email';
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = 'Blablabla... the url to confirm is: '. $url;

    return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
}
```

**6. Hook on the login page to check the $_GET, looking for user_id and token.**

Here we check the token and the user. If everything is okay, update the user meta `has_confirm_email` to 1, so the user can connect, and add a message : "Your email has been confirmed, you can now log in"

```
add_action( 'login_init', 'custom_login_init');
function custom_login_init(){
    if(!empty($_GET['token']) && !empty($_GET['user_id'])) {
        if(get_the_author_meta( 'confirm_email_token', $_GET['user_id']) === $_GET['token']) {

            // Set the has_confirm_email to 1 so the user can now log in
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'has_confirm_email', 1);
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'confirm_email_token', '');

            echo 'Your email has been confirmed, you can now log in';
        }

    }

}
```

---

**7. Time for thinking**

Okay, after all of his, i'm gonna think a little, and read what i have tell you, to check if there is no mistake ^^. **Tell me if you need more explanations.**

I think this is a good start for you, and if you find the **right hooks**, you will achieve this rapidly.

**Be careful** on some hooks that i have used, because your theme may have use a custom registration or something.

Comment: Hi Alex! Whoa, thanks for all this! I actually just found where inside the theme was the tiny line of code responsible for the auto login after registration (now commented of course). What I did is probably not the most elegant way to do it but here it is for future references (new answer to my own question).

Comment: Hi Alex, I actually have another similar project to work on but the solution I applied to the other one seems to not be working. Therefore I am going to explore yours. I will come back to you to tell you how it goes...

Comment: Okay tell me if you need more help. I'm interested in it too ! If you want to talk with me, go to my profile, you will find how to write to me

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

1. added a column in the table wp_users to receive the email confirmation code
2. built a plugin ([details here](http://www.webtipblog.com/change-wordpress-user-registration-welcome-email/)) called user-emails that allows me to bypass the first email sent upon registration by redefining the function wp_new_user_notification (in which I generate the confirmation code, add it to the user in the DB and send a confirmation email of my own sauce)
3. redefined the wp_authenticate function inside the same plugin user-emails to allow me to check if the email has been confirmed (column value not null)
4. created a page for the confirmation with the email and code passed to it that, in case of success, display a message and a link to the home page in order to login
5. finally got my hands on that one tiny line of code responsible for the auto login after registration located in the page user_auth.php inside the theme folder itself (that file also contains the layout for the login and registration form)

   ```
   wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, true, $secure_cookie );
   ```
6. made sure to display a message after registration informing the user to check his email for the confirmation email